# how to transfer Data from textboxes and combobox to listview with group?

Tags: vb.net, listview

I'm not familiar with these groupings in vb.net. My problem is I don't know how to code this. I have a sample only which I add items and groups in listview on its properties. This picture will help to understand my problem. [image: 1]

Also I want to total the items of discounted items and w/o discount items. Please help me for this.

Comment: Show code of your sample - how you added items to the ListView.

Comment: Actually I don't have code for that, I just made it without writing code, it was all on the properties of listview and other components. I was hoping that someone can help me giving a code. The picture that I was uploaded is the one I want exactly to make. I hope you can help me with that. Thank you!